# Right alignment of ionic icons

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to right align ion icon by default they are appearing in left side. How can i do this? Can anybody help me?

```
<div class="bar bar-footer no-line ">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-navigate-outline icon"></i>
    <i class="icon ion-document-text icon "></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `text-align:right` or `float:right`

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. If you just want to right align you could have used simple css as @ManishPatel mentioned. Is there some other issue in this?

Comment: I had tried these both but icons are not shifting towards left

Comment: Left? or Right?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.bar` has a `display:flex` property as per `ionic.css`
So a `justify-content: flex-end;` should work for you.

Note the **flex-right** class i added to the `bar-footer`.

See the following snippet:

```css
.flex-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bar bar-footer no-line flex-right">
  <i class="icon ion-ios-navigate-outline icon"></i>
  <i class="icon ion-document-text icon"></i>
</div>
```